# Matlab Code-Include Iteration to QR Algorithm Gram-Schmidt - The Iterations of A will converge to Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, gram-schmidt

Still need to add the iteration to the Matlab Code of the QR Algorithm using Gram-Schmidt to iterate until convergence as follows:

I am having trouble completing the code to be able to iterate the algorithm that displays $Q$. The eigenvalues will become clear in the diagonal after so many iterations of the formula noted below which will give the next $A$.  So far I have that the code will calculate $Q_0$ from $A_0=A$, which will be used in the following:

The iteration is such that $$A_{m+1}=Q_{m}^T*A_{m}*Q_{m}$$

Then the first iteration will give me $A_1$, which I will now use the algorithm to obtain the next $Q_1$, but getting stuck on the iteration part of the code. I need it to take each new Q, calculate in the above formula and display the next A. But, for now my code only calculate $Q$ from my initial $A$.

I need for the code to display $A_1, A_2,...$ until the eigenvalues become apparant on the diagonal. The eigenvalues will display nicely with this process. (Cannot us the eig function)

Matlab code so far:

```
function [Q R]=QR_GramSchmidt(A) % QR decomposition by Gram-Schmidt method

A=[3,1,0;1,4,2;0,2,1]; % I am testing

n=3; % Testing

[n n]=size(A);

Q=zeros(n);

R=zeros(n);

R(1,1)=norm(A(:,1));

Q(:,1)=A(:,1)/R(1,1);

for j=2:n

    Q(:,j)=A(:,j);

    for i=1:j-1

        Q(:,j)=Q(:,j)-A(:,j)'*Q(:,i)*Q(:,i);

        R(i,j)=A(:,j)'*Q(:,i);

    end

    R(j,j)=norm(Q(:,j));

    Q(:,j)=Q(:,j)/norm(Q(:,j));

end
```

end

See below picture of $A_8$ producing $Q_8$, then $Q_8$ is used in the iteration formula to produce $A_9$ which has the eigenvalues in the diagonal (You could see it converging previous to $A_9$).

[[Result of Manually entering each new Q to obtain the next A-Eigenvalues are in the diagonal as it converged][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grtzt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grtzt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. 
Run it. Then do the following multiplication $QR$, it will turn out to be $A$. You will also get that $Q$ is the orthogonal matrix $Q^TQ = I$ and $R$ is upper triangular. You can print $A_i$ (values of $A$ at iteration $i$) as follows

```
function [Q R]=QR_GramSchmidt(A)
[n n]=size(A);
Q=zeros(n);
    R=zeros(n);
    R(1,1)=norm(A(:,1));
    Q(:,1)=A(:,1)/R(1,1);

for j=2:n
    Q(:,j)=A(:,j);
    for i=1:j-1
    Q(:,j)=Q(:,j)-A(:,j)'*Q(:,i)*Q(:,i);

    R(i,j)=A(:,j)'*Q(:,i);

    fprintf(['At iteration i = ',num2str(i),' QR is equal to ']) % print Ai
    Q*R
end
R(j,j)=norm(Q(:,j));
Q(:,j)=Q(:,j)/norm(Q(:,j));
fprintf(['At iteration j = ',num2str(j),' QR is equal to '])
    Q*R
end   
end
```

Output will be as follows

```
>> A=[3,1,0;1,4,2;0,2,3];
>> [Q,R] = QR_GramSchmidt(A)
```

At iteration i = 1 QR is equal to 
ans =

```
3.0000    2.1000         0
1.0000    0.7000         0
     0         0         0
```

At iteration j = 2 QR is equal to 
ans =

```
 3     1     0
 1     4     0
 0     2     0
```

At iteration i = 1 QR is equal to 
ans =

```
3.0000    1.0000    0.6000
1.0000    4.0000    0.2000
     0    2.0000         0
```

At iteration i = 2 QR is equal to 
ans =

```
3.0000    1.0000   -0.2609
1.0000    4.0000    2.7826
     0    2.0000    1.5652
```

At iteration j = 3 QR is equal to 
ans =

```
 3     1     0
 1     4     2
 0     2     3
```

Q =

```
0.9487   -0.2741    0.1576
0.3162    0.8224   -0.4729
     0    0.4984    0.8669
```

R =

```
3.1623    2.2136    0.6325
     0    4.0125    3.1402
     0         0    1.6550
```

> > 

Comment: I am getting stuck on how to code the iteration so that I may run it so many times, thus showing A1, A2, ..

Comment: OK. I have edited.

Comment: Something is not quite right. For instance the matrix I am using will need to be iterated I believe it was 7 times when I manually tested it to obtain the eigenvalues. Where A_7=(Q_6)^T * A_6 * Q_6 resulting in eigenvalues of 5.346, 2.722, -0.068.  So, I am in need of obtaining a new Q to obtain the next A, not the breakdown of Q and R. So QR method will calculate each new Q to obtain the next A and then display each A, ie: A1, A2,...., A7 in this case.  Sorry - I hope that I explained well :)

Comment: But the eigenvalues of A are 1.2087, 3 , 5.7913 .. In the end, you get QR = A, where Q is orthogonal and R is upper triangular. Hence, it is correct.

Comment: So sorry my test matrix last digit is 1 not 3 like I noted

Comment: I have nothing to add, really. You also get $QR = A$ where $Q^TQ = I$ and $R$ is upper triangular.

Comment: Looking at the code you ran, the eigenvalues do not appear on the diagonal.  Need for the code to display each new A matrix for each iteration until the eigenvalues become obvious.

Comment: Eigenvalues of what ? and appear where ?

Comment: In case you want the eigenvalue of A to appear at each iteration, i.e. the eigenvalues of $A_i$, all you have to do is $eig(Q*R)$ instead of $Q*R$ which come after the two lines:
    fprintf(['At iteration i = ',num2str(i),' QR is equal to ']) % print Ai
and:
fprintf(['At iteration j = ',num2str(j),' QR is equal to '])

Comment: The algorithm is such entering A gives me Q, then A1=((Q0)^T)*A0*Q0, Then running A1 through the algorithm give me Q1. Then A2=((Q1)T)*A1*Q1, etc. Each matrix Ai will display and after so many iterations Am will be such that the eigenvalues can be seen in the diagonal. So my current code give me Qi for each Ai, but I haven't figured out how to get it to iterate as noted

Comment: I cannot use the "eig" function

Comment: You current code performs GramSchmidt to product the Q and R matrices. Gram Schmidt does not compute the eigenvalues of a matrix.

Comment: Also, kindly mention that you have edited the title of the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The output of my code as I have it displays only Q, for the matrix A that I enter.  So I just need the code to additionally take that Q answer, calculate it in (Q_i^T)*A_i*Q=A_i+1 giving me my next A, continuing the process for as many iterations as I need.

Answer (score 0):

Just implementing some code here..

```
function [T,Q,R] =basicqr(A,niter)
%
%
%
T = A;
for i=1:niter

    [Q,R] =qr(T);
    T=R*Q;
end

end


A=[3,1,0;1,4,2;0,2,1];
n=1000;

[T,Q,R] = basicqr(A,n);
[V,D] = eigs(A)
T

V =

    0.1518    0.9201   -0.3610
   -0.4658   -0.2556   -0.8472
    0.8718   -0.2968   -0.3898


D =

   -0.0687         0         0
         0    2.7222         0
         0         0    5.3465


T =

    5.3465    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    2.7222    0.0000
         0         0   -0.0687
```

the eigenvalues are right...they're just switched...you see.

You need to use a deflation technique..

```
function d = qralgH(B)
% QRALGH QR algorithm with shifts and deflation  
%        after applying Hessenberg reduction.

% Iterate over eigenvalues

A = hess1(B);

for n = length(A):-1:2
  % QR iteration
  while sum( abs(A(n,1:n-1)) ) > eps
    s = A(n,n);
    [Q,R] = qr(A-s*eye(n));
    A = R*Q + s*eye(n);
  end 
  % Deflation
  d(n) = A(n,n);
  A = A(1:n-1,1:n-1);
end
% Last remaining eigenvalue
d(1) = A(1,1);

% d = flipud(sort(d));

function d = qralg(A)
% QR algorithm with shifts and deflation.

% Iterate over eigenvalues
for n = length(A):-1:2
  % QR iteration
  while sum( abs(A(n,1:n-1)) ) > eps
    s = A(n,n);
    [Q,R] = qr(A-s*eye(n));
    A = R*Q + s*eye(n);
  end 
  % Deflation
  d(n) = A(n,n);
  A = A(1:n-1,1:n-1);
end
% Last remaining eigenvalue
d(1) = A(1,1);
end
end

function H = hess1(A)
% HESS1  Reduce a matrix to Hessenberg form.
% (demo only--not efficient)
% Input:
%   A      n-by-n matrix
% Output:
%   H     m-by-n upper Hessenberg form

[n,n] = size(A);
H = A;
for k = 1:n-1
  Q = eye(n);
  z = H(k+1:n,k);
  v = [ -sign(z(1))*norm(z)-z(1); -z(2:end) ];
  P = eye(n-k) - 2*(v*v')/(v'*v);   % HH reflection
  Q(k+1:n,k+1:n) = P;
  H = Q*H*Q';
end
H = triu(H,-1);

end

A=[3,1,0;1,4,2;0,2,1];
n=1000;

[T,Q,R] = basicqr(A,n);
[V,D] = eigs(A)
T
d = qralgH(A)

T =

    5.3465    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    2.7222    0.0000
         0         0   -0.0687


d =

    5.3465    2.7222   -0.0687
```

Comment: Can you determine based on my code what I need to add to have the algorithm take the Q it produces and plug it into the formula I have noted to obtain the next A value, continue iterating this way until convergence of the eigenvalues? I have run this manually, and have found convergence by A_7

Comment: Im currently on the road and accidently put it in there. Typically you use hessenberg reduction. It isnt gram schmidt exactly. Halves the computations.

Comment: Youre missing multiples things. Once im home i can post more. But this is classic gram schmidt. It typically goes to hessenberg first. Then there is deflation. Sometimes you use block techniques

Comment: Thank you. It will converge with adding the basic iteration formula to the code, taking the current Q Matlab produces, obtaining the next A. Do this 7 times and it works :)

Comment: Right but theyre in the wrong place.

Comment: Oh...I will have to look at that.

Comment: please your code and norm of   $ \|A-Q T Q'\| $  . If $ A=  Q T Q'$  you should see some difference

Comment: 2-norm and the Matlab code calculates Q, so all that is left to worry about is iterating at the end to obtain each new A.

Comment: I think there is some language difficulty here...

Comment: Given an initial A matrix, my code produces Q for that matrix. I just need this iteration part of the code inputted:  A_{m+1}=Q_{m}^T*A_{m}*Q_{m}, so it will print out each new value of A, based on the previous Q, for however many iterations I input. I think we are just overthinking it :)

Comment: @user565684 you don't generally know, you can put two conditional statements. A bound on the error and bound on iterations. Have two arguments one for error and one for iterations. However the standard QR iteration convergess slowly. Like I said. Also Classic Gram Schmidt isn't good. That is why I said don't use it.

Comment: I'm not sure on the best approaches, but it was one that we were to experiment with using the iteration approach to see how it converges to the eigenvalues.

Comment: You can implement the other one by taking the difference between the two eigenvalues approximations and setting a parameter epsilon and seeing if it converges to it. One second.